# How to override Externalizable to Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization

Hi I have classes that extend some given interfaces which I can't change. And those interfaces implement `Externalizable`. But I want to serialize my objects using regular Java serialization.

Basically I want the serialization to ignore `Externalizable` and use `Serializable` only

Any ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can if you control the OutputStream creation.

Typically we use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` to write serializable objects. This method checks flag 'enableOverride'. If the flag is true it calls method `writeObjectOverride()` that can be overridden by subclass of `ObjectOutputStream`.

So, the solution is the following. Create subclass of `ObjectOutputStream` that implements `writeObjectOverride()` as following:

```
protected void writeObjectOverride(Object obj) throws IOException {
    if (isMySpecialClass(obj.getClass())) {
        // call writeOrdinaryObject(obj, desc, unshared); using reflection because this method is private
        return;
    }
    // fall back to regular mechanism.
}
```

As you can see from the comment you will have to call some methods of base class using reflection because they are private (do not forget call `setAccessible(true)`). But it is possible. I believe that this task could be done withing a couple of hours.

Good luck.

BTW yet another solution is using bytecode modification. You can modify the byte code on the fly using various libraries, so make class to implement `Serializable` instead of `Externalizable`. But I personally like the first way more.

Comment: Is `writeOrdinaryObject` supposed to be called by reflection? Or it is a hack?